# How to override computations in database?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, web

I have columns in database called `basic_salary`. Aside from `basic_salary`, there is another column in particular table called `exempt_rate`.

Now, I want to override the `basic_salary` data for example. (if `rate_exempt` is `True` then no changes in `basic_salary` needed then if `rate_exempt` is `False` I need to create computation for it.

Example:

```
basic_salary * hours_work * payroll
```

How can i achieved it on every codeigniter function without changing the value of `basic_salary` in database?

Comment: Do your calculations need to be stored somewhere or is this only being used for displaying purposes?

Comment: if in mysql : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html if in SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing some details (such as of you want to just display the variable number or store it somewhere; or if you need to do it in many places or just one, for example) you could do this:

`$calc = ($rate_exempt === true) ? $basic_salary : $basic_salary * $hours_work * $payroll;`

By doing the above, the `$calc` variable would take the appropriate value depending on whether `$rate_exempt` is true or not

If you need to do this in many places, you could have this snippet in a shared model or in a custom helper, pass all the data from the database as an argument and return a response. For instance, do it as a helper:

```
function modifySalary($basic_salary, $exempt, $hours, $payroll)
{
  $calc = ($exempt === true) ? $basic_salary : $basic_salary * $hours * $payroll;
   return $calc;
}
```

Then, just load the helper in any place you need it and call it using

`modifySalary($basic_salary, $exempt, $hours, $payroll);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new meaning to field with a same name in your select:

```
SELECT if(rate_exempt = "True", basic_salary, basic_salary * hours_work * payroll) as basic_salary
```